# Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $X$. Prove or disprove that the closure of the interior of $E$ equals the closure of $E$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $X$. Prove or disprove that the closure of the interior of $E$ equals the closure of $E$.

At a glance, I thought it's false and was thinking about a counterexample in real line, but I couldn't. At this point, I'm not even sure if this is true or false.

Comment: Do you know a famous dense subset of $\mathbb R$...

Comment: you mean $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: So, the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ while the closure of the interior of $\mathbb{Q}$ is empty??

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in the comment section, Q is dense in R but the interior of Q (with respect to R) is the empty set. To see this, simply note that there is no open neighborhood in R that only contains the rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $E=\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable,
$$\mathbb{Q}=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{q_n\}$$
Where $\{q_n\}$ denotes the single element set. Since $\{q_n\}$ is nowhere dense and closed in the complete metric space $\mathbb{R}$ , it follows by the Baire Cathegory Theorem that $\mathbb{Q}$ has empty interior.

Comment: Do you really believe that you need the Baire category theorem in order to prove that the interior of $\Bbb Q$ is empty?